# Justboom dac zero

Tags: phat-dac

If I were to install rasbian and changed volume in OS would it change volume on the DAC zero or do I need to connect the rotary encoder to change volume?

Comment: I suspect that rotary encoder affects the sound via the OS (as opposed to electrically), so no you do not need it.

Comment: Awesome and thanks for the help with my questions tomas lol.

Comment: My play is to use a tochscreen, dac and an analog to digital converter for joysticks all with the raspberry pi simultaneously so I'm trying to work the pins out lol. It's kind of kick my butt and you're helping a lot

Comment: I hope you get it to work.